# Out of memory exception

Tags: c#, .net, crash

I am getting out of memory exception occasionally during program startup.  The stacktrace is given below. I am getting this crash only at customer machine.

***What steps should I follow to identify the root cause?***

```
[369][4/29/2011 18:32:15:343]-ERR -[ThreadId = 7916, UIFramework_ICEVisionPro_GUIExceptionHandler.LogException]-System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory.

   at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHdcInternal(IntPtr hdc)

   at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.CreateBuffer(IntPtr src, Int32 offsetX, Int32 offsetY, Int32 width, Int32 height)

   at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.AllocBuffer(Graphics targetGraphics, IntPtr targetDC, Rectangle targetRectangle)

   at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.AllocBufferInTempManager(Graphics targetGraphics, IntPtr targetDC, Rectangle targetRectangle)

   at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.Allocate(IntPtr targetDC, Rectangle targetRectangle)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
```

Comment: Are you making any `Bitmap` object and processing the same ? if so i believe there is not enough memory available for the process to perform the same

Comment: Are you disposing of all unmanaged resources?

Comment: @dandan78: I am not sure. This is becuase Some screens were developed by us and some were developed by customer. Is there any tools to identify whether dispose is invoked on the unmanaged resources in the application?

Comment: Add a bounty or edit question to add more details, don't create more questions that are the same. Users have been banned for that.

Comment: @Maanu, in the other question you mentioned that you were loading 30 screens at startup. Why not include this information again? This is almost certainly the cause of the error...

Comment: I have seen this with GDI+ items.  Do you have a profiler?  Do you know how many times the piece of code generating the exception is called during program start up?

Comment: Funny title: "Memory out of exception" :-) Shouldn't it be "Out of memory exception"?

Comment: @ScruffyDuck from personal experience, I'd be amazed if running out of memory when using GDI actually threw a proper OutOfMemoryException. I did quite a bit of work with large image files a while back, and not once did I see OOM thrown, even when trying to grab 1GB of memory for a single image. GDI's error reporting is comedic at best.

Comment: @Frosty840 LOL 'comedic at best'... I have the exact same experience. I would rather describe it as tragic however...

Answer (score 2):

use a decent memory profiler to help find the root cause of the issue

Answer (score 0):

From the trace above I understand you are using windows.forms. Mem leaks in windows forms programs may be due to forgetting to unsubscribe events on closing the form (subscribers preventing disposing of form). There are
[a few articles](http://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=282) and [tutorials](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/ANTS_Memory_Profiler.aspx) that suggest that this is a pretty common error in forms programming, so may be you could check it out. Of course having said that, it may not quite fit with your case (out of mem occuring in program startup).

If the memory leak occurs in managed code, using a memory profiler is probably a good idea. I mostly used the [ANTS Mem Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/), it has nice graphs and statistics and a friendlier UI in general than most.

If however the leak occurs in unmanaged code [(like for this guy here)](http://esmithy.net/2007/06/25/finding-unmanaged-memory-leaks/) you are in for a ride. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Memory_Leak_Detection.aspx) may be of help getting you started.

All in all you may have a lot of reading ahead trying to understand memory management in .net applications, how the gc generations work etc., and all this can eat up a lot of your time.

Good luck!